# 3 dimensional cube is equinumerous to any of its sections, which contains more that 1 point.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

As far as I understand this kind of problem reduces to proving that $\mathbb{R}^{2} \sim \mathbb{R}^{3}$. I wanted to confirm if I do understand it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Simply show $\mathbb R \sim \mathbb R^2$.
To do that show $(0,1)$ equinumerous
$(0,1)\times(0,1)$ by interweaving the digits.
Map $(0.abcd\dots, 0.xyzt\dots)$ to $0.axbyczdt\dots$
Exclude numbers ending in $9999\dots$

Comment: Why is it enough to prove $\mathbb{R} \sim \mathbb{R}^{2}$

Comment: Because you can prove the desired proposition from that.